# How to automatically include/load css and js from modules in CodeIgniter using HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have some modules in modules folder that have css and js folder and I am thinking of the way how to approach the automatic load of all this css and js files to my header of the template.

I was thinking of creating 2 modules called **cssloader** and **jsloader** that will be included in the header section of the template.

They would contain some php script that will put the urls of css (and js) in an array and this array will be outputed in the template like e.g.:

```
<?php echo Modules::run( 'cssloader/cssloader/_css_include_for_frontend' ); ?>
```

The urls will be grabed by some script that will be searching modules folder of the CI application and looking for css folder within and a file **load_css.php** with some defined constants or variables like

```
$css_loader_frontend['slider'] = array('slider.css', 
                                       'slider_ie6.css'
                                      );
$css_loader_backend['slider']  = array('slider_admin.css');
```

This file will contain files that will be loaded e.g. slider.css (within slider module css folder)

And the similar scenario for javascript stuff.

Is my approach right or not and you would do it somehow different?

What do you think about it?

What would you do different and more effective?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think this [template class](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html) can help you, though, I was wondering why are you accessing assets files inside modules, I'm not well versed but as far as I know you should access files such as img, js, css and so on just on the level of system and application folders in a folder that could be named "public" or "assets" to avoid "Directory access is forbidden."

Comment: I am using HMVC approach. Something like Drupal, but much simpler.